# JSON_FORCE_OBJECT in lower version of PHP

Tags: php, json

My PHP server doesn't accept second parameter for json_encode (and I need JSON_FORCE_OBJECT).     Is there any way to achive simmilar effect as JSON_FORCE_OBJECT if server doesn't support it? Mybe you know some custom functions simmilar to json_encode?

Comment: There's one in upgradephp. Also, switch to a better hoster at the nearest chance.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't solve my problem but @Markus solution is good enough :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, too:

```
$data = array(
    'foo' => (object) array('bar' => 'foo'),
);
echo json_encode($data); // should output {"foo": {"bar": "foo"}}
```